# Strange Behavior when Splitting a String

Tags: java

I am trying to split a string using a delimiter and I'm getting some odd results when I grab values from different cells in the String array. Example:

```
dataString = (String) hashMap.get("LCSSAMPLEREQUEST_sampleRequestString");

System.out.println(dataString);

String dataStringSplit[] = dataString.split("quantity|&^&|");

String tempString = dataStringSplit[0];
```

Here is the line in dataString before the first delimiter:

```
"sortingNumber|&^&|1|-()-|ID|&^&|1|-()-|DROPPED|&^&|false|-()-|"
```

Now when I do a `System.out` of `'tempString'`, I get a string with no value.

If I do `tempString = dataStringSplit[1]`, then I get a value of `'sor'`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd just write a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. For example, the fact that you're getting it out of a hash map is irrelevant. I strongly suspect that the fact that `split` works with a regex is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

`"quantity|&^&|"` should be `"quantity\\|&\\^&\\|"`. `|` and `^` are  a meta character in regex. in order to treat it as a normal charcter you should escape it with backslash

Comment: @jlordo. Because they need not be escaped in Regex.